# JavaScript Error in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have one form page that submits data to the database from a popup window.I added one disabled button js for the submitting data once.It does not work on ie11 but works for other browsers perfectly.

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // disables the button specified and sets its style to a disabled "look".
    function disableButtonOnClick(oButton, sButtonText, sCssClass)
    {
        // set button to disabled so you can't click on it.
        oButton.disabled = true; 
        // change the text of the button.
        oButton.value = sButtonText; 
        // IE uses className for the css property.
        oButton.setAttribute('className', sCssClass); 
        // Firefox, Safari use class for the css property. 
        oButton.setAttribute('class', sCssClass);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function disableButtonOnClick(oButton, sButtonText, sCssClass)
    {
        oButton.disabled = true; 
        // change the text of the button.
        oButton.value = sButtonText; 
        // IE uses className for the css property.
        oButton.setAttribute('className', sCssClass); 
        // Firefox, Safari use class for the css property. 
        oButton.setAttribute('class', sCssClass);
    }
</script>

Comment: Avyy lmao, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: But has nothing to do with the script. I guess it has some browser issue.

Comment: On IE go to "Setting -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Browsing -> Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)" and un-check the option. If you encounter javascript errors IE will break on the error and you can open a debugging window. You will be able to pinpoint the error and the line number the error is encountered.

Comment: Why are you using `setAttribute` instead of directly setting the property?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 )
oButton.setAttribute('className', sCssClass); 
else
oButton.setAttribute('class', sCssClass);
```